# How to click on link with Python and Selenium successfully?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am looping through rows which each have a link and an index value that I assign to it. In addition to selenium, I am also using Beautiful Soup API to check page html.

The main issue is that once I have found the link index that I want to use, I execute `links[index].click()` and it will only work occasionally.

`Error`: `list index out of range`

When I double checked, I see that my index is still in range of the list but is still not working

```py
 # Each link is confirmed to work, but only works every other time the script is run
 page_html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
 links = [link1, link2]
 rows = page_html.find_all('tr',recursive=False)
 index = 0
 found = False
 for row in rows:
        col = row.select('td:nth-of-type(5)')
        for string in col[0].strings:
            # If column has a "Yes" string, let's use the index of this row
            if (string == 'Yes'):
                found = True
                break
        # Break from loop if we already have the row that we want
        if found:
            break
        # If not found, continue adding to index value
        index += 1

# This is the part of the code that does not work consistently
links[index].click()
```

To debug this I attempted the following:

```py
 def custom_wait(num=3):
    driver.implicitly_wait(num)
    time.sleep(num)
 attempts = 0
 while attempts < 10: 
     custom_wait()
     try:
        links[index].click()
     except:
        PrintException()
        attempts += 1
     else:
        logger.debug("Link Successfully clicked")
        break
```

When I run this code, it says that the link is successfully clicked but again it mentions that the index is out of range.

Comment: index starts from 0, not 1. the second iteration is bound to fail, because there is no links[2]

Answer (score 0):

If the page contains more than 2 rows, it's not necessarily a surprise it throws an exception :O

The `links` list contains 2 values (`index-0`, `index-1`). If the third `row`'s `col` does not contain the string 'Yes' you don't `break` from the `for` loop and increment the `index` variable.

So at the third `row` the `index` = 2 and the `links` list does not have anything at `index-2`, hence you get the IndexError

Why don't you loop over the links instead?

```
found = False
for link in links:
    link.click()
    rows = page_html.find_all('tr',recursive=False)
    for row in rows:
        col = row.select('td:nth-of-type(5)')
        for string in col[0].strings:
            if (string == 'Yes'):
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            break
    if found:
        break
```